# Staggered Conformation Classification

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers

I was working on an assignment I had a question about conformations of a molecule about a single bond.

Given a random molecule like this with multiple large substituents on one side of the $\ce{C-C}$ bond (in this case, $\ce{CH3}$ & $\ce{C2H5}$), is the molecule considered to be anti when the largest substituents on either side of the $\ce{C-C}$ bond are opposite of each other? (i.e. would the $\ce{CH3}$ need to be an $\ce{H}$ atom to be considered in the anti conformation)?

[image: Newman projection of pentane]